# How to get channel method in the IntegrationFlowBuilder understand spel expression for the channel name?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a channel name in a header of the message. I want to send the message (with all the headers on the message) to that channel. I am trying to define an IntegrationFlow for the same. For example, the name of channel I want to submit the message to is set in the channelName header on the message and my flow definition is as follows:

```
public IntegrationFlow someFlowDefinition(){
 return IntegrationFlows.from("channelA")
 .channel("headers['channelName']")
 .get();
}
```

The problem here is .channel() does not understand spel expressions. So it thinks the name of the channel is  "headers['channelName']"

I also tried to use the SpelExpressionParser, but couldnt get set the right context (shown as ??? below).

```
public IntegrationFlow someFlowDefinition(){
 return IntegrationFlows.from("channelA")
 .channel(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("headers['channelName']").getValue(???))
 .get();
}
```

As I understand, I need to set the Message as the context, but not sure how to get a reference to the Message in the flow definition

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

`.channel()` is static; you need a `Router`.

Use `.route("headers['channelName']")`.